# AngularJS $http get request is not correctly encoding dates inside object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please look at this issue.

When I'm trying to send object (which contains dates as properties) via $http (type GET) - I'm getting URL which contains ":".

For example object:

```
var a = {date:"15:36", name:"Test"}
```

I'm expecting, that I will recieve something like "site.com?date=15%3A36&name=test"

But in actual I get: "site.com?date=15:36&name=test"

If I understand correctly - the reason is in: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js

Line 50:

```
parts.push(encodeUriQuery(key) + '=' + encodeUriQuery(serializeValue(value)));
In my example - it is object, not array. First of all - it is serializeing value. (serializeValue(value))
```

Line 13-18

```
function serializeValue(v) {
  if (isObject(v)) {
    return isDate(v) ? v.toISOString() : toJson(v);
  }
  return v;
}
```

It is object, but it is not date (it contains date as property). So we get json string.

After it - it is encoding data to URI query.

I found it here: github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/720012eab6fef5e075a1d6876dd2e508c8e95b73/src/ngResource/resource.js

(Lines 405-411) (could not add 2 links, sorry me).

```
 function encodeUriQuery(val, pctEncodeSpaces) {
    return encodeURIComponent(val).
      replace(/%40/gi, '@').
      replace(/%3A/gi, ':').
      replace(/%24/g, '$').
      replace(/%2C/gi, ',').
      replace(/%20/g, (pctEncodeSpaces ? '%20' : '+'));
  }
```

It encodes with `encodeURIComponent` input data, but after it is returning values `@`, `:`, `$`, `,`.

Is it AngularJS' bug, or did I do something wrong? I use AngularJS version 1.5.6. Please let me know your thougths, or ideas.

Comment: which back-end you use ? for get request ?

Comment: @31piy thank you a lot for editing grammar errors. My english is not so good as I want :-) 
I'm using ASP.NET WEB API server as backend.

Answer (score 1):

Use $httpParamSerializerJQLike [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Example :

```
$http({
    url: URL,
      method: 'GET',
      params:  { date:"140:30", number:"10" },
      paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
})
```

Comment: I tried to use it. But seems, that heart of this logic is also encodeUriQuery function. parts.push(encodeUriQuery(prefix) + '=' + encodeUriQuery(serializeValue(toSerialize)));  It is in "jQueryLikeParamSerializer.serialize()".